# How to access the args

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

I am learning C# programming language. Can someone help me regarding this? I tried adding the string(directory for my raster map).

> string Raster = @"C:\Raster.tif";

How to add it to array so that it can pass to this code:

> Dataset ds = Gdal.Open( args[0], Access.GA_ReadOnly );

```
class GDALReadDirect {
    
    public static void usage() 

    {
        Console.WriteLine("usage: GDALDatasetRasterIO {GDAL dataset name} {output file name}");
        System.Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
 
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        if (args.Length < 2) usage();

        // Using early initialization of System.Console
        Console.WriteLine("");

        try 
        {
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /*      Register driver(s).                                             */
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            Gdal.AllRegister();

            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /*      Open dataset.                                                   */
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            Dataset ds = Gdal.Open( args[0], Access.GA_ReadOnly );
        
            if (ds == null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't open " + args[0]);
                System.Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Raster dataset parameters:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Projection: " + ds.GetProjectionRef());
            Console.WriteLine("  RasterCount: " + ds.RasterCount);
            Console.WriteLine("  RasterSize (" + ds.RasterXSize + "," + ds.RasterYSize + ")");
            
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /*      Get driver                                                      */
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */  
            Driver drv = ds.GetDriver();

            if (drv == null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't get driver.");
                System.Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Using driver " + drv.LongName);

            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /*      Processing the raster                                           */
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            SaveBitmapDirect(args[1], ds, 0, 0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize);
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

If i change the args[0]  to Raster from code:

> string Raster = @"C:\Raster.tif";
>
> Dataset ds = Gdal.Open( args[0], Access.GA_ReadOnly );

it can display ouput on console :
[image]

but it will not execute the below code for the args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aazUf.png).
How can i pass the map to the code?

Comment: `args[0]` is a single string, since `string[] args`. It is unclear what you mean by adding `string Raster` to `args[0]`. As its stands your question is rather unclear.

Comment: i want to add link the code to read the raster map from my pc. How can i insert the map to code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your project is compiled, a `.exe` is generated. Open a console and browse to the folder containing the .exe.

You can now launch your program and use arguments. In example :

```
c:\someFolders\bin\debug>myProgram.exe "C:\Raster.tif"
```

You can now use args[0] to get the string `"C:\Raster.tif"`

---

You can use many arguments to your application. In example, the code below will display all arguments passed to the application.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
}
```

When executing it using those arguments :

```
c:\someFolders\bin\debug>myProgram.exe 42 "a string" differents words "hello World !"
```

It will output :

> 42
>
> a string
>
> differents
>
> words
>
> hello World !